# Variable Scope and Visibility in Java

Tags: java, variables, methods, scope

I am making a vacation and vacationdriver. The vacation file will serve as my blueprint and the driver will be the interactive portion of the program creating instances of vacation. I have everything working perfectly, but when I add in the one value I am missing to my print statement of line 47 of the vacation driver class I break the program.

I need to call the value for numSales which I thought is declared in line 42. When I type in numSales on line 47 at the beginning and in the middle of the output as shown I get a red line underneath and Eclipse tells me **"numSales cannot be resolved into a variable"**. What do I need to do to get the value of numSales to be actively output in the print statement on line 47 of the vacation driver?

Here is the vacation class:

```
    package cbrownmod4;

    import java.text.NumberFormat;

    public class Vacation {

// money formatting
NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

// instance variables
private String vacationName;
private int numSold;
private Double priceEach;

// empty constructor
public Vacation() {
}

// partial constructor
public Vacation(String n, int s, double e) {
    vacationName = n;
    numSold = s;
    priceEach = e = 0;
}

// updatSales method
public int updateSales() {
    int updateSales = 0;
    updateSales = updateSales + numSold;
    return updateSales;
}

// totalValue method
public double totalValue() {
    double totalValue = 0;
    totalValue = totalValue + (numSold * priceEach);
    return totalValue;
}

// toString method
public String toString() {
    return vacationName + " has been sold " + numSold + " times for " + money.format(priceEach) + 
            " each for a total value of " + money.format(numSold*priceEach);
}

// getters and setters
public String getVacationName() {
    return vacationName;
}

public void setVacationName(String vacationName) {
    this.vacationName = vacationName;
}

public int getNumSold() {
    return numSold;
}

public void setNumSold(int numSold) {
    this.numSold = numSold;
}

public Double getPriceEach() {
    return priceEach;
}

public void setPriceEach(Double priceEach) {
    this.priceEach = priceEach;
}

}
```

Here is the vacation driver:

```
    package cbrownmod4;

   import java.text.NumberFormat;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class VacationDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    // ask for the number of vacations and read it into numVacations
    System.out.println("How many vacations are there?:");
        int numVacations = input.nextInt();

    // ask for the number of sales people and read it into numPeople
    System.out.println("How many sales people are there?: ");
        int numPeople = input.nextInt();

    // beginning of loop for number of vacations
    for(int i = 0; i < numVacations; i++) { 

        //ask for the name and price and read these into variables
        System.out.println("What is the name of vacation #" + Integer.toString(i+1) + "?:");
            String name = input.next();

        System.out.println("How much does " + name + " cost?: ");
            Double price = input.nextDouble();

        // create a Vacation instance using the data obtained above
        Vacation vacay = new Vacation (name, i, price); 

        // loop through the sales people    
        for(int j = 0; j < numPeople; j++) {

            // ask for the sales for the current vacation and read it in
            System.out.println("What are the sales for the current vacation by person #" + Integer.toString(j+1) + "?:");
                int numSales = input.nextInt(); // line 42

            // call updateSales with this number
            numSales = vacay.updateSales(); 

        } //end of inner loop
        //where line 47 begins  
        //print out this vacation info
        System.out.println(numSales + " trips to " + name + " were sold for " + money.format(price) + " for a total of " + money.format(numSales * price));

    } //end of outer for loop

} //end of main

}
```

Due to requests to provide a snippet of the portion of the code not working here is the bit thats proving me problems:

```
    //print out this vacation info
        System.out.println(numSales + " trips to " + name + " were 
    sold for " + money.format(price) + " for a total of " + 
    money.format(numSales * price));
```

NOTE: If you take out the numSales in the snippet of the vacation driver, the program executes correctly but does not have the correct output because it is missing the necessary output variable

The clear concise question would be - why doesn't numSales work when I use it like shown in the short snippet. Again my problem is that Eclipse says "numSales cannot be resolved into a variable."

Comment: just to note, if you take out the numSales on line 47 of the vacation driver, the program executes correctly but does not have the correct output because it is missing the necessary output variable

Comment: TL;DR Try to formulate a clear and concise question

Comment: there is a lot of code, and line numbers are not shown in the snippet. Can you compact the code to the smallest example that is not working? That would help anybody who is having a look at the code

Comment: Last time I posted on here my question was taken down because I didn't post enough code and my question was too vague and now it's too much. I got yelled at because because I was asking people to do my work because I didnt have enough code so I have actually provided it to show you Ive done something. Just read the bottom if its too long. I edited the question for you.

Comment: Well, if you refer to line numbers then at least put a comment in the code that shows which line is 42 or 47.  If you expect users to count the lines or to copy and paste the code into an editor then you expect too much.

Comment: There's a middle road between posting all your code and posting nothing. The expectation is that you post a [mcve]. In this case, the error that you're having can be reproduced with: `{ int numSales = 0; } System.out.println(numSales); // numSales can not be resolved to a variable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you declare `numSales` inside a for {} block.

You need to declare it before the for block:

```
    int numSales = 0;  // set initial value in case numPeople is 0 and the loop never runs

    // loop through the sales people    
    for(int j = 0; j < numPeople; j++) {

        // ask for the sales for the current vacation and read it in
        System.out.println("What are the sales for the current vacation by person #" + Integer.toString(j+1) + "?:");
        numSales = input.nextInt();  // line 42; this value is never used?  it is overwritten below

        // overwrite the never-used value from line 42?? 
        numSales = vacay.updateSales(); 

    } //end of inner loop

    // now numSales is still visible, because it was declared on this same 'level' and not in an inner block
    System.out.println("numSales: " + numSales);
```

The value set in line 42 is never used, and is overwritten in line 45, so you might as well call `input.nextInt();` without setting the value to `numSales`.

Comment: I tried declaring before the for loop like shown and I am still getting the same error from eclipse. If I initialize to 0, I get rid of the error but I am still getting 0 in my output.

Comment: I suspect that you're getting another error now.  This code should work (though I didn't test it, typed in browser).

Comment: I made some updates to clarify.  Please see the current version of the answer.